# Re-map alt + cmd + H, os x Lion

Tags: macos, operating-system, command, osx-lion, shortcut

Just recently made the switch from Windows to Mac and use the alt + cmd + H shortcut alot.
However, I would like to re-map the key combination to something more convenient (say, alt + cmd + D).

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `System Preferences` and go to `Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts`
2. Select `Launchpad & Dock`.
3. Uncheck `Turn Dock Hiding On/Off`. This will free up `Cmd-Alt-D`.
4. Select `Application Shortcuts`.
5. Click the `+` button to add a new binding to `All Applications`.
6. Type in the text `Hide Others` in the `Menu Title` text field.
7. Click in the `Keyboard Shortcut` box and type `Cmd-Alt-D`.